# How can I get the correct Bluetooth name in Windows with .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

Inside the Windows Device Manager, I can configure my own Bluetooth Name, different from the Windows machine name:

[image: Windows Device Manager Screenshot]

I'm trying to get this name with .Net:

```
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
```

...

```
var btDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
foreach (var btDevice in btDevices)
{
    var btAdapter = await BluetoothAdapter.FromIdAsync(btDevice.Id);

    var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdapter.BluetoothAddress);

    string MyBluetoothName = bluetoothDevice.Name;
}
```

But instead of "MyBluetoothName" I get "Bluetooth 68:a8:6d:26:46:51". This is the name of the correct device, but not the name, I entered for it.

But if I look for my Windows device via Bluetooth from my Android device, I see the correct "MyBluetoothName" name:

[image: Android Screenshot]

How can I get the correct Bluetooth name with .Net?

Comment: Which Bluetooth library are you using?

Comment: @ewerspej: .Net. (32feet is for me too buggy and incomplete.)

Comment: Some libraries use a "Friendly Name" property for the manually provided device name. Are there any properties like that? Also, are you connecting to the device via Bluetooth or BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)? Some devices don't advertise their name via BLE by default

Comment: You are trying to access BluetoothDevice object's name. The bluetoothDevice class represents a remote Bluetooth device, not a local Bluetooth Radio. To access the local radio name use BluetoothAdapter.GetRadioAsync() and then use Name property of the Radio object returned. Also you can try Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko: bluetoothDevice is the local device, identified with the same Mac address like shown in my Device Manager screenshot. The radio shows the class name only, too.

Comment: @Willy, Ok, then try to do it with BluetoothDevice class, its your rights. Once you can get it working, try to read docs and start using Radio object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Windows DLLs directly:

```
BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS btFindRadioParams;
IntPtr findHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr deviceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

btFindRadioParams.dwSize = 4;
findHandle = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ref btFindRadioParams, out deviceHandle);
if (findHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var btDefaultAdapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
    do
    {
        BTH_LOCAL_RADIO_INFO localRadioInfo = new();
        int bytesReturned;
        if (DeviceIoControl(deviceHandle, IOCTL_BTH.GET_LOCAL_INFO, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref localRadioInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(localRadioInfo), out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        if (localRadioInfo.localInfo.address == btDefaultAdapter.BluetoothAddress)
        {
            var localBluetoothName = localRadioInfo.localInfo.name;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (BluetoothFindNextRadio(findHandle, out deviceHandle));
}
```