# How to get Extended Inquiry Response for a connected bluetooth device in UWP or Winform?

Tags: winforms, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher

I need to get the EIR data of connected Bluetooth device. How can it be done in UWP or Winform?

I got some data using LE advertisement watcher. Where I got data sections and there is a 0x09 where I can get the complete local name. 0xFF has the manufacturer data.

But is there any way to get EIR for BT not LE/LE adv?

Comment: Do you want to get the complete local name of all Bluetooth devices?

Comment: I do not think it is possible on Windows platforms. There is some IOCTRL code that looks like designed for that but when you try to execute it OS returns operation not supported error. And in WDK it is declared as "blocked".

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, yes the complete local name. For Classic Bluetooth, not from LE ADV. Could you please let us know if something is available?

Comment: @MARJANKHAN If you need to get remote device's name (for classic or for LE) you do not need access to EIR. You can use Name property of a BluetoothDevice class. Or do you need local radio name?

Comment: You can try to use Win32 API [BluetoothFindFirstRadio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstradio) in WinForm. You can refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74004552/how-can-i-get-the-correct-bluetooth-name-in-windows-with-net

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, this name can be changed. So I need the EIR actually.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, the mentioned link did not help as this name is not what I need. Could you please check if EIR of BT is available?

Comment: @MARJANKHAN It is not available on Windows platform.

Comment: @MARJANKHAN I have been looking deeper on your problem and found that starting from Windows 7 MS Bluetooth driver uses EIR data internally to get device's name.